# Call single mocha test using `import` statement instead of `require`

Tags: testing, reactjs

I have a simple test where I'd like to test a service and it's method on front end. On the back-end I use `require()` to fetch modules but the front end uses **webpack** and `import`.

My test:

```
const testee = require('../network-template.service');

describe('getTemplates', function () {
    it('shall return templates from server', function (done) {
        console.log(testee);
        done();
    });
});
```

My test class:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:3000/api/network-templates';

class NetworkTemplateService {
    getTemplates(){
        return fetch(ENDPOINT, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept' : 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(ports)
        })
            .then(response => ({response}))
            .catch(error => ({error}));
    }
```

Is there a simple and fast way how to run this test? I like how on backend I am compiling nothing and can run all the tests immediately without any setup.

Comment: if you want to use import and test your component in front-end i think you have to pre-compile it so you can test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel has a `require()` hook that can be used to transpile code on the fly, so you don't have to do any setup before running your tests.

To install:

```
npm i babel-register --save-dev
```

To use it, you can add this line in your `mocha.opts` file:

```
--compilers js:babel-register
```

Or, you can add this as a command-line flag.  If you have a `test` script in your `package.json`...

```
"scripts": {
    "test" "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-register"
}
```

Comment: thx, it's working just fine. I am using Jetbrains PhpStorm. For its purposes I had to install `babel-register` globally & instead of `mocha.opts` I used `Extra Mocha options` in `Run/Debug configurations`.

Comment: I see.  I use IntelliJ for JavaScript development, and I also like to run my tests though the IDE.  From my experience, the `mocha.opts` file is respected, so you can do it either way you want.  The reason I lean towards `mocha.opts` is because I also like to run my tests in the command line with the `mocha` binary from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add this line to your `package.json` and pre-compile it with babel.

```
..."scripts": {
        "test":"mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register ./test/example_test.js"
}...
```